# Get-Help about* finds only a single article

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

According to the book "Learn Windows PowerShell in a Month of Lunches" there should be various about-articles in the help system which present further background information on a specific topic. E.g. about_common_parameters should describe the eight common parameters each cmdlet supports.

However, executing `Get-Help about*` on my PowerShell 4 instance immediately shows about_BITS_Cmdlets. According to `Get-Help *` this is the only article starting with `about_`.

I already updated the help system with `Update-Help -UICulture "en-us"`...

Any reason why those articles are not installed?

Edit: Windows 8.1 if that matters.

Comment: Just did, nothing changed.

Comment: Did you start the PowerShell console "as Administrator" before running `Update-Help`?

Comment: Nope. And that's the solution, thank you. Oh boy...

Comment: (as a side note: anybody knows why those help files are not installed per default?)

Comment: Microsoft made a fundamental shift with PowerShell version 3.0 and later, to use update-able help documentation. I disagreed with that at the time, but it's not terrible once you get used to it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell must be run "as Administrator" for `Update-Help` to work correctly.